# How to obtain historical adjusted beta using Bloomberg excel function?

Tags: excel, bloomberg

As stated in title.

I would like something like:

```
BDH("5 HK EQUITY","Adj_Beta","01/01/2009", "12/31/2011")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking for a field, you can use the `FLDS` function. If you type `FLSD ADJUSTED BETA` in your terminal, you will get a list of fields that are relevant.

In this case the first field is `BETA_ADJ_OVERRIDABLE` which is what you are looking for.

```
=BDH("5 HK EQUITY","BETA_ADJ_OVERRIDABLE","01/01/2009", "12/31/2011")
```

Note that you can provide overrides if you want (click on the field on the FLDS screen to see a list of the parameters you can override).